# Is there any way that the react native app always ask for the permission i.e. camera permission?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, permissions

Like React-Native app only asks at once and once allowed to use a camera of a
the particular device it saves the permission in its cache.

**So how can we refrain the device to cache the permissions?**
Or
**How can we programmatically delete the cache?**

Comment: This isn't react-native.  On iOS (and presumably Android, but I don't know) you only get one chance to ask the user;  If they say no then then only way they can provide access is to go into settings and give your app permission (similarly, if they say yes, they can withdraw permission in settings). If you have asked and you don't have access then all you an do is show a message to the user telling them they need to go into settings if they want to use the feature in your app that requires the camera

Comment: @Paulw11 android is a essentially the same but it asks for permission twice (theoretically it can be more but user has to un-check "never ask again" while denying second time which rarely happens). Since android 11 user can decide to [grant camera permission one time only](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#one-time) but it there's still an option to grant it permanently.

Comment: okay so you are saying that there is no solution for this